# Determine whether a function $F:E_3\longrightarrow E_3$ is injective and/or surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $F:E_3\longrightarrow E_3$ defined by 
$$
F(\mathbf v)=\mathbf v\times(\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k).
$$
Determine whether $F$ is injective, surjective or bijective.

**My attempt.** $F$ is not injective because if $\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$, then $F(\mathbf v)=\mathbf 0$. But also if $\mathbf v'\neq\mathbf 0$ and $\mathbf v'$ is parallel to $\mathbf i + \mathbf j +\mathbf k$, then $F(\mathbf v')=\mathbf 0$. Hence $\mathbf v\neq\mathbf v'$ but $F(\mathbf v)=F(\mathbf v')$. Is this proof correct? Moreover, how can I determine if $F$ is surjective?

Thank You

Comment: Note that $f(v) \times (i+j+k) = 0$, hence it cannot be surjective.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry I do not understand. Can I conclude that $F$ is not surjective since $F$ is linear and $E_3$ is $3-\text{dimensional}$, as José Carlos Santos suggests?

Comment: You can. I was just giving an explicit was of showing why it is not surjective. If $f$ was surjective, there would be some $v$ such that $f(v)$ is non zero and perpendicular to $i+j+k)$, hence the cross product would be non zero. Hence it is not surjective.

Comment: @copper.hat I do not understand why $F(v)\times (i+j+k) = 0$. Can you explain that? Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. And since $F$ is a linear map between two $3$-dimensional vector spaces which is not injective, it cannot be surjective.

You can also prove that $F$ is not surjective observeng that every vector in the range of $F$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf k$. So, for instance $\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf k$ itself doesn't belong to the range of $F$.

Comment: I want to prove the non-surjectivity without using linearity of $F$. But I do not understand the attempt of copper.hat in the above comments. Is there another way to prove it? Thank You

Comment: @Redeldio I've edited my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Does the vector $\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k$ not belong to the range of $F$ because $(\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k)\cdot(\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k)\neq0$?

Comment: @Redeldio Right. $(\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf k).(\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf k)=\|\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf k\|^2=3$.